# How to ignore special characters and spaces in string?

Tags: java, regex

So i developed this code to convert a word to phone numbers and how do i code it to ignore the spaces entered while displaying the result?

So what i meant is to allow the user to entered spaces between the words but is not reflected in the result.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Scanner  console = new Scanner(System.in);


{  
System.out.println("Enter the a word to be converted : ");

String  Letter = console.next ();
Letter = Letter.toUpperCase();
Letter = Letter.toLowerCase();
String  Number="";

int count=0;
int  i=0;

while(count < Letter.length())
  {switch(Letter.charAt(i))
   {case 'A':case 'B':case 'C': case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':
              Number += "2";
              count++;
      break;
  case 'D':case 'E':case 'F': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
               Number += "3";
              count++;
      break;
   case 'G':case 'H':case 'I': case 'g': case 'h': case 'i':
              Number += "4";
              count++;
      break;
    case 'J':case 'K':case 'L': case 'j': case 'k': case 'l':

              Number += "5";
             count++;
      break;
    case 'M':case 'N':case 'O': case 'm': case 'n': case 'o':
          Number += "6";
              count++;
      break; 
    case 'P':case 'R':case 'S': case 'p': case 'r': case 's':
              Number += "7";
              count++;
      break;
    case 'T':case 'U':case 'V': case 't': case 'u': case 'v': 
            Number += "8";   
            count++;
      break;
    case 'W':case 'X':case 'Y':case 'Z': case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z':
         Number += "9";
         count++;
      break;
      }
    if(  count==3) {
       Number += "-";
   }
   i++;
           }     
    System.out.println( Number );

   }


   }}
```

Comment: Btw, [Character.toUpperCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29).. now simplify your code.

Comment: add a default case and do nothing in that... but if you want that user should not enter it then go for byte array checking method or a check by character wise... It would be easier to understand your problem if you told your input and expected output

Comment: Haha i just wanted to further improve this, new to java. Also thanks for your input

Comment: @CoderNeji my expected input is to allow the user to use both upper and lower case character as well as spaces between the words.....expected output is to have the word converted into numbers even if there is special characters or spaces in the input.

Comment: Desired out put is [call home] displayed as [225-54663]

Comment: @CoderNeji but in my latest additional of code. when i enter [call home]...the result is [225-5].

Comment: because space is not found in the dir list thats why i have added a byte checking in my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  String content = "asda saf oiadgod iodboiosb dsoibnos";
  content = content.replaceAll("\\s", "");
  System.out.println(content);
```

**For your code**

```
System.out.println("Enter the a word to be converted : ");

    String Letter = console.nextLine();
    Letter = Letter.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    Letter = Letter.toUpperCase();
    Letter = Letter.toLowerCase();
    String Number = "";
```

Comment: hello i have tried this method but what it does it just ignore all the characters i input after space.

Comment: e.g. call home- it will display only call which is 225-5. The 'home' will not be converted.

Comment: Oh it worked now!. But i do have to ask ("\\s", ""); what is the significant of the characters inside to bracket to allow it to work>?

Comment: '\s' is the regex for white space but as backslash is a special character in java we use \\s so that java will take the regex as '\s'. so now the method replaces all white space,tab and \n with the second argument which is "".

Happy to help! Please accept the answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

To ignore spaces you can use the following:

```
String.trim();
```

This will `trim` all of the blank spaces from the String. See [String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) for more information!.

And to check whether the String contains anything besides letters you can use:

```
public boolean isAlpha(String name) {
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

If you want speed, or for simplicity, you can use:

```
public boolean isAlpha(String name) {
    return name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Scanner  console = new Scanner(System.in);


{  
System.out.println("Enter the a word to be converted : ");

String  Letter = console.next ();
Letter = Letter.toUpperCase();
Letter = Letter.toLowerCase();
String  Number="";

int count=0;
int  i=0;

while(count < Letter.length())
  {switch(Letter.charAt(i))
   {
   case 'A':case 'B':case 'C': case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':
              Number += "2";
              count++;
      break;
  case 'D':case 'E':case 'F': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
               Number += "3";
              count++;
      break;
   case 'G':case 'H':case 'I': case 'g': case 'h': case 'i':
              Number += "4";
              count++;
      break;
    case 'J':case 'K':case 'L': case 'j': case 'k': case 'l':

              Number += "5";
             count++;
      break;
    case 'M':case 'N':case 'O': case 'm': case 'n': case 'o':
          Number += "6";
              count++;
      break; 
    case 'P':case 'R':case 'S': case 'p': case 'r': case 's':
              Number += "7";
              count++;
      break;
    case 'T':case 'U':case 'V': case 't': case 'u': case 'v': 
            Number += "8";   
            count++;
      break;
    case 'W':case 'X':case 'Y':case 'Z': case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z':
         Number += "9";
         count++;
      break;
    default:
        //Ignore anything else
        break;
      }
    if(  count==3) {
       Number += "-";
   }
   i++;
           }     
    System.out.println( Number );

   }


   }}
```

By using default in your switch case you can ignore all other responses.So if the y type anything which is not included in your switch it won't add to your count or number.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your characters from your string which are non-alphanumeric with blank(`""`) and then do your processing using that string. You can use [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

For **Eg:**

```
String str = "abc..,df.,";
String alphaNumericStr = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
System.out.println(alphaNumericStr); // Prints > abcdf

while(count < alphaNumericStr.length()) { // using alphaNumericStr instead of Letter
    ...
```

---

**Another approach** (I would prefer this): Refer answer by @KeshavPandey

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simulate a numeric keypad, then you should probably use the `blank space` and append your string with `0`.

Most of the mobile phones have `blank space` on the number `0` key.

```
case ' ':
    Number += "0";
    count++;
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code might help you.
I just optimized your code above. You can replace the characters with numbers using the String APIs instead of iterating the string character by character and generating the number.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);    
String str = console.next();

// To trim the leading and trailing white spaces
str = str.trim();

// To remove the white spaces in between the string
while (str.contains(" ")) {
    str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
}

// To replace the letters with numbers
str = str.replaceAll("[a-cA-C]", "2").replaceAll("[d-fD-F]", "3")
    .replaceAll("[g-iG-I]", "4").replaceAll("[j-lJ-L]", "5")
    .replaceAll("[m-oM-O]", "6").replaceAll("[p-sP-S]", "7")
    .replaceAll("[t-vT-V]", "8").replaceAll("[w-zW-Z]", "9");

System.out.println(str);
```

If you want to insert an "-" after 3 digits, you can use the following piece code after the above conversion.

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(str);
buff.insert(3, "-");

System.out.println(buff.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just add an additional case statement to check for the characters you want to avoid. Then, "do nothing" when this is hit...

In your case of just wanting to skip spaces, you could add an additional case specific to the ' ' character, and/or a default case;

```
case ' ':
default:
    break;
```

Comment: Will definitely give this a try! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, i have tried this but it only converted the characters before the space. e.g. call home: 225-5

Comment: home which is after the space is skipped too.