# I have to check pallindrome string.I am getting a wrong answer when I enter String having numeric values.For ex."0P"

Tags: java, string

I have to ignore all special characters in the string.I have created a new string s1 including only alphanumerics characters.Then,made a reverse string s2 and then checked if they are pallindrome or not.

```
class Solution 
{
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s)
    {
        char c,ch;
        String s1="";
        String s2="";
        s=s.trim();
        s=s.toLowerCase();
        if(s=="")
            return true;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            c=s.charAt(i);
            if(c>=97&&c<=122||c>=0&&c<=9)
                s1=s1+c;
        }
        for(int j=s1.length()-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            ch=s1.charAt(j);
            s2=s2+ch;
        }
    if(s1.equals(s2))
        return true;
    else
        return false;  
    }
}
```

Comment: What result do you consider correct for input '0P'? Right now you filter out all digits.

Comment: False should be returned for "0P"..as it is not pallindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you are using `c>=0&&c<=9` for checking `c` for digit. It is wrong, cause `'0' == 48` and `'9' == 57` and you have to use c>=48 && c<=57

---

And I want to give you some comments about your code:

1. String is an immutable object in java and a lot of string
   concatenating - is a very bad practice. Please use StringBuilder.
2. You can use `s.isEmpty()` instead of `s==""`
3. `Character` class has static methods `isDigit` and `isAlphabetic`, whic are checks char for digit or alphabetic
4. If you will use StringBuilder, you can invert string just by     `stringBuilder.reverse()` method
5. At the end of the method, you return true if `s1.equals(s2)` and false - overwise. You can just use `return s1.equals(s2);`
6. And you can iterating through the string with `for (char c : s.toCharArray())` cycle

And the final code is

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s)
{
    s=s.trim();
    s=s.toLowerCase();

    if(s.isEmpty())
        return true;

    StringBuilder sanitizedString = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(c) || Character.isDigit(c))
            sanitizedString.append(c);
     }

    String s1 = sanitizedString.toString();
    String s2 = sanitizedString.reverse().toString();

    return s1.equals(s2)
}
```

And you can use regexp from @RR_IL answer for avoiding the cycle.

Comment: I have added some comments about your code, I hope it will be useful. If you have any questions, you are welcome

Comment: Ok Sir Thankyou.Sir I haven't learn lists in java.Are arrays enough or I should learn it.?

Comment: I would like to recommend you learning Java collections (List, Map, Set). They are used veeery frequently.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "@ Test!#@!#!@92432432";
String tmp = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
System.out.println(tmp);
```

### Prints

```
Test92432432
```

Ref:
[How to ignore special characters and spaces in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716511/how-to-ignore-special-characters-and-spaces-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = s.length() - 1; 
    while (i < j) { 
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j)) 
            return false; 
        i++; 
        j--; 
    }
    return true; 
}
```